# Clear text field value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I understand this is an easy question but for some reason this just isn't working for me.  I have a function that is triggered everytime a drop down menu is changed.  Here is the relevant code that is suppose to grab the current value of the text field, if a value exists, clear it that is contained within the .change function:

```
var doc_val_check = $('#doc_title').attr("value");
    if (doc_val_check.length > 0) {
        doc_val_check == "";
    }
```

I feel like I am missing something very simple.

Comment: Here I am five years later and while I can spot the issues in my code now, I am happy to see this question helping so many others still. :)

Comment: It's 2019, and still going :)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

```
doc_val_check == "";   // == is equality check operator
```

should be

```
doc_val_check = "";    // = is assign operator. you need to set empty value

                       // so you need =
```

You can write you full code like this:

```
var doc_val_check = $.trim( $('#doc_title').val() ); // take value of text 
                                                     // field using .val()
    if (doc_val_check.length) {
        doc_val_check = ""; // this will not update your text field
    }
```

To update you text field with a `""` you need to try

```
$('#doc_title').attr('value', doc_val_check); 
// or 
$('doc_title').val(doc_val_check);
```

But I think you don't need above process.

---

#### In short, just one line

```
$('#doc_title').val("");
```

#### Note

`.val()` use to set/ get value in text field. With parameter it acts as setter and without parameter acts as getter.

Read more about **[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val)**

Comment: Calling `doc_val_check = ""` won't update the `value` property of the element; you'll just end up with a variable that's an empty string that's completely separate from your element's `value` property.

Comment: Summery of all answers after while!

Comment: @Tooraj In my answer I tried to explain all aspects, if you think its a summary then its that, but down vote is not expected

Comment: @Tooraj thanks bro, I like to get suggestion from all and try to update myself.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to clear the text field, use:

```
$('#doc_title').val("");
```

Comment: Since I was echoing the php session value , the $('#doc_title').attr("value", ""); didn;t worked with me.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of all those:

```
$('#doc_title').attr("value", "");
```

Comment: he can use `.val()` function.

Comment: Can and **should**. Value is a property, not an attribute; setting the attribute with `.attr()` isn't an absolute guarantee that you'll set the property.

Comment: This worked like a charm.  Thank you.  Once I'm allowed to, I'll select this as the answer.

Comment: @Yuschick can be made still simpler.

Comment: The ones that use `.val()` are better answers. This would be non-typical jQuery code to use `attr` to change the value.

Answer (score 6):

What you need is:

```
if ($('#doc_title').val()) {
  $('#doc_title').val('');
}
```

Comment: The `.html()` doesn't apply here.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yep, that's true.

Answer (score 6):

In simple way, you can use the following code to clear all the text field, textarea, dropdown, radio button, checkbox in a form.

```
function reset(){
    $('input[type=text]').val('');  
    $('#textarea').val(''); 
    $('input[type=select]').val('');
    $('input[type=radio]').val('');
    $('input[type=checkbox]').val('');  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can clear it by using this line

```
$('#TextBoxID').val("");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery, then you can use this:

```
// var doc_val_check = $('#doc_title').val(); - No need of this!
if ($('#doc_title').val().length > 0) {
    $('#doc_title').val("");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use this for text clear

```html
$('input[name="message"]').val("");
```

Answer (score 2):

For the most part you just set the .val() method. All of the answers are pretty accurate, just wanted to post my results to anyone who may need to set the value via the client id that gets rendered.

```
 $('#' + '<%= doc_title.ClientID %>').val(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `doc_val_check` with an empty string. You want to assign the empty string to `doc_val_check`

so it should be this:

`doc_val_check = "";`

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery.prototype.val` to get/set field values:

```
var value = $('#doc_title').val();    // get value
$('#doc_title').val('');    // clear value
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     First Name: <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="input1"/>
>     <br/>
>     Last Name: <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="input2"/>
>     <br/>
>     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
> </form>
> ```

Comment: use autocomplete="off"

Comment: It won't work for clear text - we have to use jquery for clear text

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#[element id]').val(null);
```

or

```
$('.[element class]').val(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have element with visible blank text just do this:

```
$('#doc_title').html('&nbsp;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```js
function checkValue(){
  var value = $('#doc_title').val();
  if (value.length > 0) {
        $('#doc_title').val("");
        $('#doc_title').focus();  // To focus the input 
    }
    else{
    //do something
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="doc_title" value="Sample text"/>
<button onclick="checkValue()">Check Value</button>
</body>
```