# how to clear a field value in a form using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Please let me know how to clear the value of a field in a form on form load using jQuery.
I am calling a service on form load and wanted to clear the value for one of the fields.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Please search. there are duplicates upon duplicates of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+clear+input

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clear text field value in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951809/clear-text-field-value-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Clear input field value using `.val()`.

```
$('input#input_id').val('');
```

Referens: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2