# Reseting textbox values after successful ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am now trying to reset the values of textbox after the ajax request was succcessfully completed.
I tried something like this

```
$('#text1').val("");
$('#text2').prop('value','');
```

But woludn't works.
These all are works in console..

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/Includes/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){             
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"validation.cfc",
                data:{method:'db_validation',fname:$('#text1').val(),Email:$('#text2').val()},
                type:"POST",
                success:function(html){
                    //what code should be written to clear textbox values after successful ajax response
                    //$('#text1').val("");   ---> This code was not working
                    $('#para').html(html);//even this code was executed.
                }
            });             
        });     
    }); 
 </script> 
 <form>     
 <p id="para"></p>  
 <input id="text1" name="txtBox1" type="text"><br />    
 <input id="text2" name="txtBox2" type="text"><br />    
 <input type='button' name='Button' value='Add User' id="btn"/> 
 </form>
```

Comment: How many elements do you have with the id `text1`?

Comment: I updated my answer and added a fiddle example. I'm sorry for comment i didn't know are you informed about answer edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  the following , It empties textbox.

```
$('#text1').val("");
```

U may have problem in ur code.

If any problem refer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951809/clear-text-field-value-in-jquery)

Also jQuery [API](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: @RPX , what do you mean by NOT WORKING?Check LINK in answer above .I give link HOW TO USE VAL . IT MUST work as its jQuery feature.Its problem that may be Causing conflicts ,or console errors , breaking further code .

Comment: @RPX , Its your work to see why .val() not working . And Again IT MUST WORK.It works on all PC ,all browsers on everyone's PC,Browser.Check what is preventing .val() To work.

And especially if you are saying

$('#text1').val("");
$('#text2').prop('value','');

This is not working , somthing wrong with YOUR code.please dont blame jQuery ,by saying "I tried but it didnt work".

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the `#para` line executing and the text remaining on the page as the form is submitted twice: by default form submission and ajax. Therefore I expect that the html in `#para` would appear for a short moment and disappear.

Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent default submission and the textboxes should be cleared unless you have duplicate IDs.

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').closest('form').submit(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:"validation.cfc",
            data:{method:'db_validation',fname:$('#text1').val(),Email:$('#text2').val()},
            type:"POST",
            success:function(html){
                $('#text1').val("");   //<----- Should work
                $('#para').html(html);  //even this code was executed.????
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Quite likely it does get submitted; therefore you want to pass `event` to the handler and use `event.preventDefault()` ... then those lines should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to reset form it's use reset method

```
success:function(html){
  $('#form').reset();
}
```

EDIT:
Sorry Thats my fail didn't check it

Here working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/baximilian/PHwHZ/1/)

it should be

```
success:function(html){
  $('#form')[0].reset();
}
```

Comment: @RPX give id to your form or use $('form') selector. But it can reset other form if it exist on your page

Answer (score -2):

If you want to clear the text box just use the text box ID as 
 in any functio

```
txtName.Text = "";
txtContactno.Text = "";
txtEmail.Text = "";
```