# Clear PHP echoed values input fields

Tags: php, html

I have a form which displays values on click from the table through the php's echo function. The echo'ing logic is as follows:

```
     //reading input
     if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $scrid=$_POST['sc'];
        $desc=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
        $cb=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['created']);
        $version=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['version']);
        if($scrid !=0){
            if(empty($desc)){$result="Description cannot be Empty";}
            elseif(empty($cb)){$result="Created By cannot be Empty";}
            elseif(empty($version)){$result="Version cannot be Empty";}
            else{
                echo $t."empty";
                $sql="INSERT INTO testmaster(ScreenID,Description,createdBy,version) VALUES('$scrid','$desc','$cb','$version');";
                if(mysqli_query($link,$sql)){                         
                         header('Location: testmaster.php');
               }else{
                    echo "Query failed";
                   }
            }
        }
    }
                      //passing table values,,,,, works perfectly fine...
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($sol)>0){
                   while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sol)){
                            echo"<tr>";

                            echo"<td><a href=testmaster.php?testid=".$row['tid'].">".$row['Description']."</a></td>";
                            echo"<td>".$row['createdBy']."</td>";
                            echo"<td>".$row['version']."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                    }
                }      
                }
        if(isset($_GET['testid'])){
        $t=$_GET['testid'];
        $query="SELECT * FROM testmaster WHERE tid='$t';";
        if($sol=mysqli_query($link,$query)){
            $modif=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sol);
            $d=$modif['Description'];
            $c=$modif['createdBy'];
            $v=$modif['version'];
            $sc=$modif['ScreenID'];

        }

//These are the input fields



echo'<td><textarea name="desc" class="form-rounded" cols=50 rows=2 
    placeholder="Description">'.$d;
    echo'</textarea></td>';
    echo'<td><input type="text" name="created" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Created By" value='.$c.'>';
    echo'</td>';

//cancel


echo "<input type='reset' class='btn button2' name='cancel' id='cancel' value='Cancel' style='height:12px; text-align:center; margin-left:10px;' >" ;
```

Neither cancel button nor the javascript codes specified in [Clear text field value in JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951809/clear-text-field-value-in-jquery/10951832) work.

I guess it's because I echo it.
 Can anyone help me with it?
Thanks in advance.... :)

P.S. All the input fields and the cancel button are inside ...

Comment: where is your `cancel` button javascript code? show us.

Comment: Have you got a `<form>` tag anywhere? A reset input type isn't going to do much without one.

Comment: @iainn.. Yes, I do.

Comment: @SurkaavS Right, can you update the question with the *complete* code then please? If what you've posted is only extracts, it's going to be very hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: Insecure query in use.  And this question has 2 upvotes because.... ?  Is it clear?  Is it echoing variables in a singke quoted string?

Comment: @iainn the code is of 250 lines and there are hell other functions working too.... I am not sure if it can be posted

Comment: @mickmackusa , I am using get because i have  no other option of passing the testid from a table using href.... :) Thanks for ur concern

Comment: The $_GET is not the problem.  You are feeding raw user data into your query.  Your query is vunerable to injection attack.  I recommend prepared statements with placeholders or if an integer then simply cast as `(int)`.

Comment: @mickmackusa , this is not where i get input from. testid is taking the values from the values already present in db. I have used mysqli_real_escape_string while getting the input

Comment: Then I will state for future researchers that your posted code is insecure and your `created` input value will truncate if contains a space because it is not double quote wrapped.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa :)

Comment: You should be checking `empty()` before trying to access/compare/escape your SUPERGLOBALs to avoid Notices. Again, `$t` makes your query vulnerable.

Comment: They are required fields... if you can notice from the code. And, yes,before executing the query, i do check. I prefer not to add them cuz it'll make my post too lengthy!! :)

Comment: Hackers don't care which fields are required.  They can type whatever they like into the address bar.

Answer (score -1):

If you've included JQuery in your code, then you can do this like that:

1. Add *clear-onclick* (or some other name) class to all fields you want empty
2. Add **onclick** handler to the button

Form code

```
 echo'<td><textarea name="desc" class="form-rounded clear-onclick" cols=50 rows=2 
placeholder="Description">'.$d;
echo'</textarea></td>';
echo'<td><input type="text" name="created" class="form-control clear-onclick" 
placeholder="Created By" value='.$c.'>';
echo'</td>';
```

Button code

```
 <input type='reset' class='btn button2' name='cancel' id='cancel' onclick="javascript: $('.clear-onclick').val(null)" value='Cancel' style='height:12px; text-align:center; margin-left:10px;' >
```

You can include jQuery as follows:

```
echo '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>';
```

Comment: can u specify where i should add this jquery? I'm pretty new to all of these.... Thank you :)

Comment: You can add this before you're echo'ing your form. It would be better if you add this between <head> and </head> of your html.

Comment: Thank you:)  but i have tried the same and it didn't help! :(

Comment: I see you're using Bootstrap, maybe jQuery is included already. Take a look in developer's console for errors. 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: sure. Thank you:)

Comment: Inside a form, a reset button does this already.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_reset  the trouble is, there is NO posted `<form>` tags in the question so it is Unclear.