# How to set empty or null value doesn't worked in Jquery change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the value in the input text to be null after the hide process

This is my view :

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="status" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Status Karyawan</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
        <option value="" selected>Pilih Status Karyawan</option>
        <option value="Kontrak">Kontrak</option>
        <option value="Tetap">Tetap</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row" id="tgl_pengangkatan" style="display:none">
  <label for="tgl_pengangkatan" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Tgl. Pengangkatan</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8 input-group">
    <input name="tgl_pengangkatan" type="text" class="form-control datepicker form-control-sm" id="tgl_pengangkatan" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row" id="tgl_berakhir_kontrak"  style="display:none">
  <label for="tgl_berakhir_kontrak" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Tgl. Akhir Kontrak</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8 input-group">
    <input name="tgl_berakhir_kontrak" type="text" class="form-control datepicker form-control-sm" id="tgl_berakhir_kontrak" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

And than, this is my script:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#status").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val === "Kontrak") {
        $("#tgl_berakhir_kontrak").show();
        $("#tgl_pengangkatan").hide();
        $("#tgl_pengangkatan").val('');
    }
    else if (val === "Tetap") {
        $("#tgl_pengangkatan").show();
        $("#tgl_berakhir_kontrak").hide();
        $("#tgl_berakhir_kontrak").val('');
    }
    });
});
```

I want to make it like that to minimize errors in the input process, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951809/clear-text-field-value-in-jquery

Comment: you can not give duplicate id to same controls. first rename your textbox id because it conflicting with your main div section. so make id unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are trying to change should be called with its name, not the id. Try changing it as:

```
$('[name="tgl_berakhir_kontrak"]').val('');
```

By the way, it's not a good practice to give identical name and id to separate elements on the same page.

Comment: no, my point was that there are duplicate uses of the same id. The div container and this element have same ID which should be avoided. Another approach would be to rename the div container with a different ID.